# Quando usar self vs $this em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Vejo como uma dúvida muito frequente:

Quando devemos usar o `self::`, ou o `$this` no PHP. Qual forma é mais adequada para o uso e qual a diferença das 2 situações?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

De forma simplificada, `$this` se refere ao objeto (instância) atual, e `self` se refere à classe. Portanto, como regra geral, usa-se `$this` para acessar membros (atributos, métodos) da instância e `self` para acessar membros estáticos.

### Herança

Quando se usa herança, no entanto, há diferença entre usar `self` e `$this` ao chamar um método da instância:

- `self::metodo()` chama o `metodo()` da classe atual;
- `$this->metodo()` chama o `metodo()` da classe usada para instanciar o objeto que está sendo executado (que pode ser uma subclasse da classe onde a chamada é feita). Você pode descobrir que classe é essa usando `get_class($this)`.

Exemplo:

```php
<?php
class Animal {
  public function teste() {
    echo "\$this é instância de " . get_class($this) . "\n";

    // chama Animal::fala(), independentemente do
    // tipo da instância
    echo "self::fala(): ";
    self::fala();

    // chama fala() na classe usada pra instanciar
    // este objeto
    echo "\$this->fala(): ";
    $this->fala();
  }
  public function fala() {
    echo "Oi\n";
  }
}

class Gato extends Animal {
  public function fala() {
    echo "Miau\n";
  }
}

// Nesse caso, self != get_class($this)
// - self == Animal
// - get_class($this) == Gato
$gato = new Gato();
$gato->teste();

echo "\n";

// Nesse caso, self == get_class($this) == Animal
$animal = new Animal();
$animal->teste();
?>
```

Resultado:

```
$this é instância de Gato
self::fala(): Oi
$this->fala(): Miau

$this é instância de Animal
self::fala(): Oi
$this->fala(): Oi
```

Comment: Boa resposta. Bem explicativa.

Comment: Curiosidade: o operador de resolução de escopo "::" chama-se [Paamayim Nekudotayim](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

Comment: Em casos que dá pra usar tanto o self:: quanto o $this, use o self:: que usa menos memória!

Answer (score 6):

A diferença é que o self é para quando a classe (ou instância), está em um contexto estático (seja um método ou propriedade), e obviamente o this é quando não é estático.

Answer (score 4):

No geral, usamos o `$this` para manter o encapsulamento e evitar colisões de informações de um objeto no outro.
Se por algum motivo você precisa compartilhar uma informação com todas as instancias de uma classe, é ai que entram as variaveis estaticas, vejamos um exemplo:

```
<?php

class Notebook
{
    private static $quantidadeDisponivel = 5;

    public function getQuantidadeDisponivel()
    {
        return self::$quantidadeDisponivel;
    }

    public function comprar()
    {
        /**
         * Realiza o processo de compra do notebook e atualiza quantidade disponivel
         */
        self::$quantidadeDisponivel--;
    }
}

$carrinhoJoao = new Notebook;
$carrinhoJoao->comprar();
$notebooksRestantes =  $carrinhoJoao->getQuantidadeDisponivel(); 
print $notebooksRestantes; // imprime 4

$carrinhoPedro = new Notebook;
$carrinhoPedro->comprar();
$notebooksRestantes =  $carrinhoPedro->getQuantidadeDisponivel(); 
print $notebooksRestantes; // imprime 3

$carrinhoPaulo = new Notebook;
$carrinhoPaulo->comprar();
$notebooksRestantes =  $carrinhoPaulo->getQuantidadeDisponivel(); 
print $notebooksRestantes; // imprime 2

$carrinhoJoao->comprar();
$notebooksRestantes =  $carrinhoJoao->getQuantidadeDisponivel(); 
print $notebooksRestantes; // imprime 1

$carrinhoPedro->comprar();
$notebooksRestantes =  $carrinhoPedro->getQuantidadeDisponivel(); 
print $notebooksRestantes; // imprime 0
```

Sem o uso da variavel statica, não seria tão simples fazer esse controle, veja só:

```
class Desktop
{
    private $quantidadeDisponivel = 5;

    public function getQuantidadeDisponivel()
    {
        return $this->quantidadeDisponivel;
    }

    public function comprar()
    {
        /**
         * Realiza o processo de compra do notebook e atualiza a quantidade disponível
         */
        $this->quantidadeDisponivel--;
    }
}



$carrinhoJoao = new Desktop;
$carrinhoJoao->comprar();
$notebooksRestantes =  $carrinhoJoao->getQuantidadeDisponivel(); 
print $notebooksRestantes; // imprime 4

$carrinhoPedro = new Desktop;
$carrinhoPedro->comprar();
$notebooksRestantes =  $carrinhoPedro->getQuantidadeDisponivel(); 
print $notebooksRestantes; // imprime 4

$carrinhoPaulo = new Desktop;
$carrinhoPaulo->comprar();
$notebooksRestantes =  $carrinhoPaulo->getQuantidadeDisponivel(); 
print $notebooksRestantes; // imprime 4
```

Como vimos, com o uso da variável statica tivemos o resultado 4,3,2,1,0
e com a variável comum tivemos 4,4,4, os computadores continuariam sendo vendidos mesmo já tendo acabado.

**(Esse exemplo é meramente educativo!)**

Answer (score 3):

`$this` é usado dentro da classe para acessar propriedades/métodos do objeto.
`self` é usado para acessar membros estáticos.

Answer (score 3):

O $this aponta para o objeto e o self aponta para a classe em si.

O self pode ser usado também quando a classe estende outra e você quer acessar a implementação dela ou do parente dela por exemplo

```php
self::teste();
```

ou

```php
parent::teste();
```

Mas geralmente o self será usado para acessar dados estáticos da classe.