# Erro ao utilizar $this em função estática

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Estou tentando utilizar uma função de uma classe da seguinte forma:

```
$database = database::select("SELECT * FROM eventos");
```

Quando executo o código, ele me retorna o erro:

**Fatal error:** Using $this when not in object context in **/var/www/html/pasta/class/config.php** on line **27**

A classe está da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
class database{

    protected static $driver = 'mysql';
    protected static $host = 'localhost';
    protected static $port = 3306;
    protected static $user = 'root';
    protected static $pass = 'vertrigo';
    protected static $database = 'noweb';
    public $link = null;

    public function __construct(){

        try{

            $this->link = new PDO(self::$driver.":host=".self::$host.";port=".self::$port.";dbname=".self::$database, self::$user, self::$pass);

        }catch(PDOException $i){

            die("Ocorreu um erro ao fazer conexão: <code>".$i->getMessage()."</code>");
        }

    }

    static function select($sql){

        $query = $this->link->query($sql);
        $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));

        return $rs;
    }
}

?>
```

Como posso arrumar isso, sendo que quero chamar as funções dessa classe da seguinte forma:

```
database::FUNÇÃO('parametros');
```

Comment: Transforme `$link` em propriedade estática e troca as ocorrências de `$this` por `self`

Comment: @rray fiz isso `$query =self::$link->query($sql);` e ele me retorna **Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object**

Comment: Resolvido. Consegui resolver jogando a conexão para uma função estatica chamada conexao() e tirando a conexão do __construct(); assim, na função select(){ } eu chamei a função self::conexao();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como métodos estáticos podem ser chamados sem uma instância do objeto ter sido criada, a pseudo-variável $this não é disponível dentro do método declarado como estático.

Propriedades estáticas não podem ser acessadas pelo objeto usando o operador seta `->`.

Chamar métodos não estáticos de maneira estática gera um aviso de nível `E_STRICT`.

Como qualquer outra variável estática do PHP, propriedades estáticas podem somente ser inicializadas usando um valor literal ou constante; expressões não são permitidas. Então você pode inicializar uma propriedade estática para um inteiro ou array (por exemplo), você não pode inicializar com outra variável, com um retorno de função, ou um objeto.  fonte: [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 0):

No seu exemplo, existe um método estático que tenta acessar um atributo de uma instancia(objeto) em algum momento foi criar o objeto? não logo `$this->algo` não estará acessivel.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Quando usar self vs $this em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575/91)