# Constructor php

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar uma classe com um `constructor` porém está me retornando esse erro. Tentei fazer algo parecido com o Java já que não programo em `PHP` ainda, porém está me retornando esse erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: typegraph in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HOPE\php\graficos.php on line 23

Já tentei usar os metodos `GETTERS` e `SETTERS` e mesmo assim não consegui solucionar.

```
class Grafico{

    private $typegraph=0;
    private $graphTitle=0;
    private $HorizontalTitle=0;
    private $sufixo=0;
    private $lineName=0; 
    private $valuesdescription=0;
    private $values=0;

    public function Grafico($typegraph_p, $graphTitle_p, $HorizontalTitle_p, $sufixo_p, $lineName_p, $valuesdescription_p, $values_p){
        $typegraph = $typegraph_p;
        $graphTitle = $graphTitle_p;
        $HorizontalTitle = $HorizontalTitle_p;
        $sufixo = $sufixo_p;
        $lineName = $lineName_p;
        $valuesdescription = $valuesdescription_p;
        $values = $values_p;
    }

    public function Printa(){

        echo $typegraph;
        echo $graphTitle;
        echo $HorizontalTitle;
        echo $sufixo;
        echo $lineName; 
        echo $valuesdescription;
        echo $values;
    }

}
```

Comment: Para pegar a propriedade da classe, use `$this->nome_da_proriedade` e o metodo printar você pode subistituir pelo [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As variáveis em que você esta dando o `echo` fazem parte da classe, logo precisam do `this` para serem acessadas. Do jeito que esta, o PHP vai procurar pelas variáveis primeiro no escopo da função/método e como não estão declaradas la ocorre esse erro.

```
public function Printa(){
    echo $this->typegraph;
    echo $this->graphTitle;
    echo $this->HorizontalTitle;
    echo $this->sufixo;
    echo $this->lineName; 
    echo $this->valuesdescription;
    echo $this->values;
}
```

Desse jeito voce esta referenciando a variável da classe, o `this` meio que aponta para a própria classe, na verdade é a instancia da classe.

A mesma coisa vale para o o método `Grafico`

```
public function Grafico($typegraph_p, $graphTitle_p, $HorizontalTitle_p, $sufixo_p, $lineName_p, $valuesdescription_p, $values_p){
    $this->typegraph = $typegraph_p;
    $this->graphTitle = $graphTitle_p;
    $this->HorizontalTitle = $HorizontalTitle_p;
    $this->sufixo = $sufixo_p;
    $this->lineName = $lineName_p;
    $this->valuesdescription = $valuesdescription_p;
    $this->values = $values_p;
}
```

Apenas reforçando, o que você estava fazendo era criar variáveis dentro do método enquanto que as propriedades da classe continuavam "intocadas".

Leia no manual do PHP essa [sessão sobre propriedades](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.properties.php), vai ajudar bastante a entender o conceito.

Comment: Cara funcionou muito obrigado, eu tentei com o $this na frente, porém meu erro era colocar o $ na frente. Poderia me explicar o por quê de não ter o $?

Comment: tentou o  $this na frente do que?  Logo no comeco tipo, `private $this->values=0;`? Foi isso?

Comment: tentei exatamente do jeito que você falou porem eu estava fazendo assim            $this->$typegraph = $typegraph_p; tanto no metodo gráfico quanto no metodo para pegar o valor.

Comment: A sintaxe é $this->propriedadedoobjeto .
$this->$variavel é incorreto . Tb me confundia no começo. :)

Comment: se você tentou algo como $this->$values ele vai tentar buscar uma variavel no escopo local chamada "values" e dar 1 toString nela e buscar uma propriedade da classe do valor "toStringed" dele, logo se não encontrar no escopo local  a "$values" ele vai fazer algo do tipo $this->null o que deve ter gerado seu erro.

Comment: Há quem use tb __construct no lugar do nome da classe para o construtor. Eu sou uma dessas pessoas. Além disso tb uso __destruct em classes de controladores genéricos que faço outras classes minhas extenderem. Nesse __destruct eu mando chamar uma view com mesmo nome do método(action) que está sendo acessado.

Answer (score 3):

Seu problema está sendo ocasionado devido ao `escopo` das variáveis. Ao referenciar/acessar um método da classe em questão, utilize o operador `$this->`.

Um outro detalhe, é que você está tentando iniciar o construtor da classe com um método de mesmo nome dela, como `JAVA` e que foi declarado obsoleto a partir da versão `5.3.3` e tornando-se um método comum, quando deveria utilizar o método [`__construct`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php).

```
<?php

public class Grafico {

    private $typegraph;
    private $graphTitle;
    private $HorizontalTitle;
    private $sufixo;
    private $lineName; 
    private $valuesdescription;
    private $values;

    function __construct(
        $typegraph, 
        $graphTitle, 
        $HorizontalTitle, 
        $sufixo, 
        $lineName, 
        $valuesdescription, 
        $values
    ){
        $this->typegraph = $typegraph;
        $this->graphTitle = $graphTitle;
        $this->HorizontalTitle = $HorizontalTitle;
        $this->sufixo = $sufixo;
        $this->lineName = $lineName;
        $this->valuesdescription = $valuesdescription;
        $this->values = $values;
    }

    public function printa()
    {
        echo $this->typegraph;
        echo $this->graphTitle;
        echo $this->HorizontalTitle;
        echo $this->sufixo;
        echo $this->lineName; 
        echo $this->valuesdescription;
        echo $this->values;
    }

}

$grafico = new Grafico(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$grafico->printa();
```

Dica de leitura: [Quando usar self vs $this em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/575/quando-usar-self-vs-this-em-php)