# Pegar o retorno de uma função em outra no controller do laravel

Tags: laravel

Tenho duas funções no controller e preciso passar o retorno de uma função para a outra e salvar numa variável, mas está dando erro.

função que retorna

```
public function getarrcontatos(Request $request){
        $value = $request->get('value');
        $ArrContatos = [];
        $ArrContatos = $value;
        return ($ArrContatos);

    }
```

Função que recebe

```
    public function store(Request $request){

          $input = $request->all();
          $obscontatos = $request->input('obscontatos');
          $result = count($obscontatos);



        for ($i = 0; $i < $result ; $i++) {


          $listacontatos = getarrcontatos();


        $contatoarray = array('idContato'=>$listacontatos[1],'ccContato'=>$listacontatos[2], 'idObsContato'=>$listacontatos[0]); 
       DB::table('contatoObsCc')->insert($contatoarray);

      }

  }
```

Estas duas funções estão no controller do Laravel.

A linha de código que da errp é:  `$listacontatos = getarrcontatos();`

Comment: Estão na mesma controller?

Comment: Sim, estão no mesmo Controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você esta referenciando uma função dentro da mesma classe que foi instanciada é necessário utilizar **$this** na chamada ao método, assim, seu código da função que recebe tem que ficar desta forma:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $input = $request->all();
    $obscontatos = $request->input('obscontatos');
    $result = count($obscontatos);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $result ; $i++) {

        // O método é referenciado por $this e o parâmetro $request é enviado
        $listacontatos = $this->getarrcontatos($request);

        $contatoarray = array('idContato'=>$listacontatos[1],'ccContato'=>$listacontatos[2], 'idObsContato'=>$listacontatos[0]);

        DB::table('contatoObsCc')->insert($contatoarray);

    }
}
```

Para mais informações sobre o uso de $this da uma olhada na resposta da seguinte pergunta:

[Quando usar self vs $this em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/575/quando-usar-self-vs-this-em-php)

Comment: eu fiz dessa forma, mas a variável $listacontatos fica vazia.

Comment: Utilize no método store antes de qualquer instrução a diretiva Log::info($request); para gravar no arquivo de log a saída e termos uma ideia do que esta sendo enviado ao método, acredito que ele não esta trazendo a chave 'value' e por isso o método getarrcontatos esta retornando vazio.

Answer (score 1):

Falta colocar o `$this`

Coloca assim:

```
 $listacontatos = $this->getarrcontatos();
```